# Apache CXF vs Apache Camel

Tags: web-services, cxf, apache-camel, mule, erp

our problems:

- a sets of existing applications (recruiting, purchasing, payroll etc..) communicate outside through various ways (email, pdf, csv file, webservices etc)
- a new ERP system we gona use(SAP or Agresso) communicates the outside through web services
- we need integrate the existing systems with the ERP system, and apply some rules

my questions:

- can we do the job by only using CXF?
- is CXF a subset of camel
- or perhaps to achieve what we want, we have to combine those two?

also Mule doesn't give a specific price for the cost, anyone had experience with MuleSoft?

thanks for time!

Comment: I think you have the answer already, the best one who make the decision is yourself, you knew the environment properly. Otherwise, you need pay consultant services which cost you about >$1000 per hour. Second, set a test/UAT environment to try both, if you really want to do it by yourself. And read this http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment by BMW is very true.

However to answer you a little more closely.

CXF is a services framework. It allows you to create SOAP, REST and even CORBA services. So yes it can help you create and consume web services.

CXF is a component used inside Camel, CXF is not a subset of camel. Camel will allow you to provide and consume web services using CXF.

Camel is a EIP(Enterprise Integration Pattern) framework which allows you to do things such as route a file to a web service. Or expose a SOAP service that talks to JMS queues etc. I know Camel also has a SAP component.

Thus Camel orchestrates the various components into routes that allows various systems to integrate.

In short you will use Camel with the CXF and other components to resolve your problems.

I have not used Mule yet but I can tell you this. You can host your Camel routes on Apache Karaf and create your own light weight "ESB" so no need to use Mule ESB.

Another alternative would be Fuse ESB and also Servicemix. THey are also capable of hosting Camel route.

I currently have several camel routes that expose web services and consume various data from files, rss feeds etc hosted on Karaf and it works like a charm.

Comment: We also use Fuse ESB which includes Apache Camel and CXF. The CXF component is for communicating with or hosting web services and the Camel part lets you wire everything else together - works really well.

Comment: Yeah @vikingsteve apache camel is the bomb.